# Trying to connect two different types of structures to create linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, structure, nodes

I'm looking for a way to connect nodes created by different structures to make linked lists and things like that. I tried several ways but I was not able to. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
struct nodeA{
    int somedata;
    nodeA* next;
};

struct nodeB{
    int someData;
    nodeB* next;
    nodeB* someAnotherNode;
};

int main(){

    nodeA* A0 = new nodeA; //Just creating some nodes... 
    nodeA* A1 = new nodeA; 
    nodeA* A2 = new nodeA;

    nodeB* B0 = new nodeB;

    A0 -> next = A1; //I can connect these nodes
    A1 -> next = A2; //in this way.

    A2 -> next = B0; //but, I can't do that!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use `std::list` if you actually need a linked list, or `std::vector` otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes and [polymorphism](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/):

```
class NodeA {
 public:
  int somedata;
  NodeA* next;
};

class NodeB : public NodeA {
  NodeB* someAnotherNode;
};

int main(){
    NodeA* A0 = new NodeA; //Just creating some Nodes... 
    NodeA* A1 = new NodeA; 
    NodeA* A2 = new NodeA;

    NodeB* B0 = new NodeB;

    A0 -> next = A1; //I can connect these Nodes
    A1 -> next = A2; //in this way.

    A2 -> next = B0; //but, I *can* do that!

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Richard, thanks for the suggestion, but having omitted, these structures are initialized within a class.

Comment: @PedroLobo I’m not sure why that prevents you from using polymorphism…

Comment: I would have suggested inheriting `nodeA` and `nodeB` from `nodeBase`, but this works too for this example.

Comment: @Richard I simplified my problem to post here. My idea is to use the nodes structures inside the class. I adapted and it worked very well. Thanks!